# How to send same text message to multiple people but they would only see their name as recipient?

Tags: sms

I have a Moto X with KitKat.

I am trying to send the same text message to multiple people.

- I do not want the recipients to see the numbers of other recipients.
- I do not want the recipients' replies to go to multiple people.
- I do not want the recipients to see who all the recipients are.
- If the recipient reply's to my text message than that message should only go to me.

Just like adding people under BCC in the email.

Any help?

Comment: Isn't this exactly how SMS behaves? In a group SMS conversation, group messages are sent as individual messages to individual recipients.

Answer (score 2):

That's how SMS usually works. When you send a text to a group of people, only they should be able to that they got it. They won't be able to see who else got the text.. unless you were sending SMS through Google Hangouts.